# How to transfer webdriver-io's browser Object via PassByReference

Tags: javascript, selenium, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm using webdriver-io v3.x in combination with Mocha.
To be able to test identical components on different sites I'd like to outsource the test into an extra function. 
To achieve this I have to transfer the browser object via some kind of PassByReference to this extra function. How can I do this?

Example Code:

```
// [...]

// this function shall be callable from every TestCase.
var testObject = function(browser) {
    return browser
        .getText('.InfoText')
            .then(function(txt) {
                console.log('txt: ' + txt);
                txt.should.equal('Information');
            });
});

describe('Sample Test Suite', function() {

    // go to a webpage for testing
    before(function() {
        browser
            .url('http://example.com');
    });

    // refer to the test definitions in the function testObject(browser)
    it('sample test case', function() {
        return testObject(browser);
    });

});
```

I can print out all attributes of the object browser in the function testObject, so a function like

```
for(var attribute in browser) {
    console.log('browsers attributes: ' + attribute);
};
```

would list all (and a few more) of webdriver-io's functions defined in the API:

```
$ browsers attributes: defer
$ browsers attributes: promise
$ browsers attributes: lastPromise
$ browsers attributes: desiredCapabilities
$ [...]
$ browsers attributes: getTabIds
$ browsers attributes: getTagName
$ browsers attributes: getText
$ browsers attributes: getTitle
$ browsers attributes: getUrl
$ browsers attributes: getValue
$ browsers attributes: getViewportSize
$ browsers attributes: hold
$ browsers attributes: isEnabled
$ browsers attributes: isExisting
$ browsers attributes: isSelected
$ browsers attributes: isVisible
$ [...]
```

But unfortunately the function browser.getText() in my method testObject appears to never reach the then block, as it doesn't print out anything on the console.

So my question is: How can I transfer the browser object with its functionalities correctly to another method, so that I can fully use it there?

Comment: This has nothing to do with pass-by-reference, which is a term of art in computing meaning passing a reference to a **variable** into a function so that the function can modify the **variable's** contents. You're passing an object reference into a function via value, which is all you need here. The problem is *timing*, not what you're passing.

Comment: More about testing async in Mocha (I *think* you're using Mocha behind the selenium bit): http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code Though it sure looks to me like you're returning a promise from `testObject` and in turn from the `it` callback...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are totally right. I forgot about that. Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@T.J.Crowder helped me to overcome this issue. Thank you very much!

I have to make my testing async.
So the solution code is to add the done function into the testCase:

```
// refer to the test definitions in the function testObject(browser)
it('sample test case', function(done) {
    return testObject(browser)
                .then(done);
});
```